# Solr Retrieve values of not stored field

Tags: lucene, solr4, solr-schema

How can I get field "to" values which is specified as **not stored** in solr schema.
This field have a copyField "text ".
**Facet causes memory out of bound,**
Is there any way to see the values without the use of facet query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not retrieve values of a field if the **< stored="false">** is set.

There are usually two parameters indexed and stored which can have different combination.

> < indexed="true" stored="true">

In this case the values are both stored and indexed. that is you can search on that field and also can retrieve it if needed in the search results.

> < indexed="true" stored="false">

In this case the value of the field is indexed i.e searchable but not stored, hence can not be retrieved.

> < indexed="false" stored="true">

In this case the value is not searchable , you can however return it in the search results.

> < indexed="false" stored="false">

In this case you can neither store nor can search the field.

The reason behind the **stored** attribute is that that Solr or rather lucene "analyzes" or transforms the input data into a more efficient form for faster and more relevant search(using different analyzers and tokenizers). Unfortunately, that analyzed/transformed data is frequently no longer suitable for display. Setting **"stored=true"** guarantees that the original data can be retrieved in its original form.